# How to realize strikethrough text in Listview with CheckBox?

Tags: android-listview, android-checkbox, strikethrough

I have a ListView with CheckBox and TextView. But when I click on Checkbox, I can’t get strikethrough text. But when I click on the last checkbox, I get strikethrough text.
[image]

> This is my GetView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_with_checkbox, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            listViewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        }else{
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        listViewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    listViewHolder.textInListView.setPaintFlags(listViewHolder.textInListView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    listViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);


                }else{
                    listViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

> This is my Main:

```
ListView listViewWithCheckBox = (ListView)RootView1.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka> listViewItems = new ArrayList<AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka>();

        listViewItems.add(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka("Nigeria"));
        listViewItems.add(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka("Ghana"));
        listViewItems.add(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka("Senegal"));
        listViewItems.add(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka("OPA"));
        listViewItems.add(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxBolvanka("KNIGA"));
        listViewWithCheckBox.setAdapter(new AimsDiaryCheckBoxAdapter(getContext(), listViewItems));
        listViewWithCheckBox.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// make Toast when click
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with these lines:

```
if (listViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    listViewHolder.textInListView.setPaintFlags(listViewHolder.textInListView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    listViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Take a look at what listViewHolder is pointing to and you are doing the isChecked() before actually calling listViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true).  Looks like a timing issue